# I have the same value appear in every row of one column in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, summary

Why does it give me the same value for the length_of_stay?(which is the value of the first row)

This is the code:

```
select price_total, check_in_date, check_out_date,
price_total / length_of_stay as price_per_day, length_of_stay
from
(select check_out_date - check_in_date as length_of_stay
from bookings b)as table1, bookings b2;
```

This is the output:

| price_total | check_in_date | check_out_date | price_per_day | length_of_stay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1428.30 | 2018-08-30 | 2018-09-03 | 357.0750000000000000 | 4 |
| 269.37 | 2020-02-11 | 2020-02-14 | 67.3425000000000000 | 4 |
| 111.93 | 2020-12-28 | 2020-12-29 | 27.9825000000000000 | 4 |
| 1131.13 | 2020-02-26 | 2020-02-29 | 282.7825000000000000 | 4 |
| 391.80 | 2020-06-11 | 2020-06-12 | 97.9500000000000000 | 4 |
| 336.00 | 2020-06-11 | 2020-06-12 | 84.0000000000000000 | 4 |
| 293.82 | 2020-02-16 | 2020-02-18 | 73.4550000000000000 | 4 |
| 2236.92 | 2018-09-24 | 2018-09-27 | 559.2300000000000000 | 4 |

Comment: you are doing a `CROSS JOIN` there, effectively making a cartesian product, this isn't what you need at all

Answer (score 2):

Because you're doing a `join`, it's easier to just repeat your `length_of_stay` logic twice.

```
select price_total, 
       check_in_date,
       check_out_date,
       price_total / (check_out_date - check_in_date ) as price_per_day, 
       check_out_date - check_in_date as length_of_stay
from bookings;
```

Comment: I had to create a subquery because length_of_stay doesn't exist in the bookings b2 table. So I calculated it and created an alias for this calculation: check_out_date - check_in_date as length_of_stay

Comment: Even though the logic is right, just beware that probably a stay that checks out the same day of check in, should have a length of 1 day (otherwise, I would advise to have a logic to avoid a divide by zero error)

Comment: @user15216987 I understand the column doesn't exist, you just need to repeat the logic to calculate `price_per_day`.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller thank you, I feel so dumb now. I started learning SQL recently so I still have bad awareness using it.